# Why doesn't sencha UI back button work on the "htc one" smartphone?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I have developed a mobile android application with a user interface back button. These buttons seem to work on the [Samsung galaxy S4 smartphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S4) but not on the [HTC One smartphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_One_series).

I am using `sencha 2.3.0` with `sencha arhitect 3.0`.

Comment: Please share more information about your app and show us some code (at least of the button definition + events binding)

Answer (score -1):

That specific error is mentioned in the Sencha forums:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?273492-Back-button-broke-in-navigationview-Sencha-Touch-2.3-Android-4.3&p=1009111&viewfull=1#post1009111

**Solution that worked for me:**

Override the core code (`class Ext.env.Feature`).

Find the method `isStyleSupportedWithoutPrefix` and replace it with this
code:

```
isStyleSupportedWithoutPrefix: function(name, tag) {
        var elementStyle = this.getTestElement(tag).style;
        if (typeof elementStyle[name] !== 'undefined' && typeof Ext.browser.getStylePrefix(name) === 'undefined') {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    },
```

Explanation: it's mix of webkit/chromium and Touch problems. Firstly, using transform on element in some cases prevent from firing touch events on this item, but theoretically Sencha Touch should deal with it. So why doesn't it? Android 4.3 or 4.2 introduces non prefixes transform property in native browser. And this is where the problem occurs. Touch still generates prefixed values to animate the element, but in the animation object non prefixed ones are kept. So, in the end, when transitioned is fired touch can't cleared with all of animated properties (and finish the animation) which prevent from firing internal event animations. On this event, Touch must do some dirty work to resume hit detection.